# Split a string of values and put them into a table

Tags: java

I have a lookup table that has a key and value pair as follows:

```
Key|Value
abc|a,b,c
def|a,b,c
fes|a,d,c
```

what I am trying to do is put them in a list as shown below with each value in a separate column

```
"abc",a,b,c
"def",a,b,c
"fes",a,d,c
```

Below is my code:

```
public class Schema {
    public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> tableList = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();  
    static 
    {
        LookupTable SchemaLookup = ContextFactory.getCurrentContext().getLookupTableManager().getLookupTable("File Layout");
        Collection<LookupTableEntry> mappings = SchemaLookup.getLookupTableEntries();
        try {
            Iterator<LookupTableEntry> mappingsIterator = mappings.iterator();
            while (mappingsIterator.hasNext()) {
                LookupTableEntry entry = mappingsIterator.next();
                String key = entry.getKey();
                List<String> values = entry.getValues();
                ArrayList<String> arrayValues = new ArrayList<String>(values);
                tableList.put(key, arrayValues);
            }
        }finally {
        }
    }
}
```

right now this is returning all of the values as one but I want to have it as individual columns. any idea on how I can split the values by comma and add them separately? (ex tabele size for all should be 4, right now its 2)

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you change the `tableList.put()` method?

Comment: as in do the split within the 2nd parameter?

Comment: Why not just do a `String#split()` before adding in the values?

Comment: What do you mean by "*right now this is returning all of the values as one*"? `List<String> values = entry.getValues();` looks like it returns you list of values. Can you be more precise what you have now and what you want to achieve?

Comment: it returns me "a,b,c" instead I want "a","b","c"

Comment: Do you mean that returned list has only one element which is `"a,b,c"` instead of three elements `"a","b","c"`? In that case can we see code you are using to fill this list so we could improve it to do what you need (or do you prefer to split result of `entry.getValues()`)?

Comment: yes you are correct, returned list only has one element where I am looking for 3. Updated code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the string in the first element of the `values` list:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayValues = 
               new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(values.get(0).split(",")));
tableList.put(key, arrayValues);
```

The element at index 0 of the `values` list is "a,b,c". You split it, get an array like `{"a","b","c"}` and create a list from it.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you don't want to or can't update code which creates `LookupTableEntry` instances. So all you can do is reading this one element `"a,b,c"`, split it on `,` and put split elements into another collection.

Do do so you can use for instance something like

```
List<String> values = entry.getValues();
ArrayList<String> arrayValues = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String token : values.get(0).split(",")){
    arrayValues.add(token);
}    

tableList.put(key, arrayValues);
```

Or one-liner

```
tableList.put(key, new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(entry.getValues().get(0).split(","))));
```

Comment: @Razvan Yes, if they are long (like this one) that is why I added it as addition to more readable code.